# How to Negate Array.protype.filter Function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the Array.prototype.filter() method to filter an array into 2 sets of elements and then iterating through those 2 sets with Knockout, though I believe the issue is JS related. I would like to take the truthy elements and make set A and the falsy and make set B. So, for falsy I attempt to negate the function, but the following error occurs. I could create a second method to perform the negation, however I'm interested in this solution. Thanks.

> Array.prototype.filter: argument is not a Function object

HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(IsSetA) -->
    <h1>Is Set A</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(!IsSetA) -->
   <h1>Is Set B</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
function IsSetA(item) {
    return item.category === 'A';
}
```

Comment: You need to negate the return value, not the predicate function itself: `Items.filter(v => !IsSetA(v))`

Comment: @Bergi - I do like this approach, but unfortunately browser support will not allow currently. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter()` requires you to pass a function that it will execute on each item. `IsSetA` by itself works because it's a function, but negating that with the `!` operator casts it to a boolean value, which simply isn't something accepted by `filter`.

Alternatively, you could either create helper functions and use them in your template:

```
function IsSetATruthy(item) {
    return IsSetA(item);
}

function IsSetAFalsy(item) {
   return !IsSetA(item);
}
```

or write the same as inline functions:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(function(item) { return IsSetA(item); }) -->
    <h1>Is Set A</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(function(item) { return !IsSetA(item); }) -->
   <h1>Is Set B</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

or use arrow functions if your target [supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) them:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(item => IsSetA(item)) -->
    <h1>Is Set A</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(item => !IsSetA(item)) -->
   <h1>Is Set B</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I like the arrow function approach, but browser support will not allow for it, so I like the inline function approach next, and I have that working now.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to negate a *function reference*. What you were trying to do is negate the *result of the function*. The positive case works (filter expects a function reference), but the negative will not, so negate the result manually:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(IsSetA) -->
    <h1>Is Set A</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko foreach: Items.filter(function(val){ return !IsSetA(val); }) -->
   <h1>Is Set B</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I did end up using this approach, and with the first filter not being inline actually as well like yours, but I went ahead and marked skreborn's as the answer in case those other options are helpful to someone in the future (and post times were the same minute :)).  Thank you very much for taking a look at this though, greatly appreciated!